# Redux toolkit useselector doesn't grab the state properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to store my current user using redux toolkit. I'm dispatching the action in the Login page and it looks like when I try to grab the user state on that page it is being set correctly. However I go to another page and try to grab the user state it returns the initial state.

This is the slice that I've written.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    value: {
      id: '',
      email: '',
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    setCurrentUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
      console.log('SETTING:', state.value)
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setCurrentUser } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

I think I'm importing my reducer to my store correctly

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './features/user/userSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
})
```

And I'm passing it through to my index

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../store'
import App from '../components/App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Here is where I'm selecting the user

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Component = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value)
```

I'm using react-redux 8 and react 17
I'd love some help debugging this.

Comment: Could you show how you are selecting the user? Also, just to be sure: are you using React 18 and React-Redux 8?

Comment: It sounds like your state tree is getting reset when you go to another page. This most likely occurs when the page refreshes. How are you currently navigating to the other page?

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve it?

Comment: @NicholasWong had the right idea on what was wrong for me. When I click on another link it causes a refresh which resets my state. This is proper behavior. You'll need to either prevent the refresh from happening or store the data somewhere persistent. I stored it in local storage cuz it was easiest for me ‍♀️